# How could keras model predict only one sample?

Tags: python, deep-learning

In my project, I want to do training off line which means that it will process samples in batch way (I set

`batch_size=100`

in `model.fit()`), and I want to predict only one sample in real time, so I use:

```
model.predict(x_real_time, batch_size=1)
```

but it shows the error:

```
`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 3) for Tensor 'input_11:0', which has shape '(165047, 3)'`
```

Could someone tell me how to solve this one? Thanks

The whole code:

```
batch_size = int(data_num_.shape[0]/10)

original_dim = data_num_.shape[1]

latent_dim = data_num_.shape[1]*2

intermediate_dim = data_num_.shape[1]*10

nb_epoch = 10

epsilon_std = 0.001



data_untrain = data_scale.transform(df[(df['label']==cluster_num)&(df['prob']<threshold)].iloc[:,:data_num.shape[1]].values)

data_untrain_num = (int(data_untrain.shape[0]/batch_size)-1)*batch_size

data_untrain = data_untrain[:data_untrain_num,:]



x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, original_dim))

init_drop = Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(original_dim,))(x)

h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(init_drop)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)

z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)





def sampling(args):

    z_mean, z_log_var = args

    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.,

                              std=epsilon_std)

    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])


decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')

decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='linear')

h_decoded = decoder_h(z)

x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)





def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):

    xent_loss = original_dim * objectives.mae(x, x_decoded_mean)

    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)

    return xent_loss + kl_loss



vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)

vae.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), loss=vae_loss)



train_ratio = 0.9

train_num = int(data_num_.shape[0]*train_ratio/batch_size)*batch_size

test_num = int(data_num_.shape[0]*(1-train_ratio)/batch_size)*batch_size



x_train = data_num_[:train_num,:]

x_test = data_num_[-test_num:,:]



vae.fit(x_train, x_train,

        shuffle=True,

        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,

        batch_size=batch_size,

        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))



# build a model to project inputs on the latent space

encoder = Model(x, z_mean)

x_test_predict = data_scale_.inverse_transform(vae.predict(x_test, batch_size=1))

x_test = data_scale_.inverse_transform(x_test)   

for idx in range(x_test.shape[1]):

    plt.plot(x_test[:,idx], alpha=0.3, color='red')

    plt.plot(x_test_predict[:,idx], alpha=0.3, color='blue')

    plt.show()

    plt.close()
```

Comment: Would you please put your whole code here?

Comment: The code of the instantiation of the model and the shape of x_real_time would help us tremendiously in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have attached code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the input layer. You should not pass in the batch size. If you want to predict with variable batch sizes you should pass in the input_shape without the batch size then you can just pass in a single sample.

So:

```
x = Input(shape=(3,))
```

Comment: Is is possible to do training by processing samples in batch way, and do prediction by processing sample in a single way? Because I have more than 10 millions samples, I want to use mini batch to do training.

Comment: Yes if you do not start with a fixed batch size you can still do batch training by passing in a batch size to the fit method.

Comment: After fitting the model, I run 
vae.predict(x_test,batch_size=1)
I show an error:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (79397,3) into shape (1,3)

It seems like the batch_size must be set properly....